# How to have all Jenkins slave tasks executed with nice?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent, nice

We have a number of Jenkins jobs which may get executed over Jenkins slaves.  Is it possible to globally set the nice level of Jenkins tasks to make sure that *all* Jenkins tasks get executed with a higher nice level?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. The "trick" is to start the slave agent with the proper nice level already; all Jenkins processes running on that slave will inherit that.

Jenkins starts the slave agent via ssh, effectively running a command like

```
cd /path/to/slave/root/dir && java -jar slave.jar
```

On the Jenkins node config page, you can define a "Prefix Start Slave Command" and a "Suffix Start Slave Command" to have this nice-d. Set as follows:

- Prefix Start Slave Command: `nice -n -10 sh -c '`
- Suffix Start Slave Command: `'`

With that, the slave startup command becomes

```
nice -n -10 sh -c 'cd "/path/to/slave/root/dir" && java -jar slave.jar'
```

This assumes that your login shell is a bourne shell. For csh, you will need a different syntax. Also note that this may fail if your slave root path contains blanks.

I usually prefer to "`Launch slave via execution of command on the Master`", and invoke ssh myself from within a shell wrapper. Then you can select cipher and client of choice, and also setting niceness can be done without Prefix/Suffix kludges and without whitespace pitfalls.

Comment: warning with this example: `nice -n -10` makes the niceness level lower (minus 10), though on a Jenkins build server, you may want to set the niceness higher instead, if your goal is to keep the machine responsive: `nice -n 10`